# Form not submitting to database in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a form in Django and the information from this form must be registered in the database. But I have a problem. The information is not recorded in the database. I guess it's the JavaScript file that's blocking it.

I remove the JavaScript file and the form works fine. But I don't want to remove the JavaScript file. How can I solve this problem?

views.py

```
def index(request):
if request.POST:
    fname_lname = request.POST.get('name')
    number = request.POST.get('number')
    newForm = models.Form(fname_lname=fname_lname, number=number)
    newForm.save()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

model.py

```
class Form(models.Model):
  fname_lname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  number = models.IntegerField(max_length=15)
  send_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

index.html

```
<div class="formbg">
           <div class="formcolor">
              <form class="forminput" method="post" action="/">
                 {% csrf_token %}
                 <div class="label">
                    <label class="labels">Ad və Soyadınız <span>:vacibdir</span></label>
                    <div class="input">
                       <input name="name" required type="text" class="inputs" />
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="label">
                    <label class="labels">Telefon nömrəniz <span>:vacibdir</span></label>
                    <div class="input">
                       <input name="number" required type="number" class="inputs" />
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="formbut">
                    <button type="submit" class="btnsubmit">Göndər</button>
                 </div>
              </form>
           </div>
        </div>

     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- SECTION19 -->


  <!-- SECTION20 -->
  <div class="security">
     <i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
     <p>SİZİN MƏLUMATLAR YADDAŞDA QALMIR VƏ 3-CÜ TƏRƏFƏ GÖSTƏRİLMİR</p>
  </div>
  <!-- SECTION20 -->

  <!-- SECTION21 -->
  <div class="finish">
     <p>Məxfilik siyasəti</p>
     <h1>* - Q7 GOLD KİŞİ GÜCÜNÜN FORMULU</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- SECTION21 -->
  <script src="{% static 'index.js' %}"></script>
```

index.js

```
let labels=document.getElementsByTagName("label");
[...labels].map(label=>{
 label.children[0].style.display="none";
});
let btnsubmit=document.querySelector(".btnsubmit");
btnsubmit.addEventListener("click",(e)=> {
e.preventDefault();
let inpts=document.querySelectorAll(".inputs");
[...inpts].map(async inp=>{
  if(inp.value==""){
     inp.style.border="3px solid red";
     inp.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[0].style.color="red";
     inp.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[0].style.display="inline-block";
  }
  else{
     inp.style.border="3px solid green";
     inp.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[0].style.display="none";
  }
 });
 if(inpts[0].value.length>0 && inpts[1].value.length>0) alert("Sifarişiniz uğurla qəbul 
 edilmişdir.Ən qısa zamanda əlaqə saxlayacağıq");
 });
```

Comment: There's nothing i can see in the js file. it just editing the style of your form.
What I am seeing is you are using `models.Form(###)` in views.py. import Form class using `from .models import Form` then use `Form(###)`

Comment: Have you tried removing `e.preventDefault()`?